# checking two Calendars against each other to see if they are are more then a week apart

Tags: java, android

I have two datepickers for search parameters but i cant have the search more then a week(to much of a load on the server) so i want to check if the first date is before the second one, and if the first date and second date are less then 7 days apart. if all is correct then return a true boolean if not false.

```
public Calendar max = Calendar.getInstance();

public boolean checkweek(Calendar cStart, Calendar cEnd) {
    Toast.makeText(this,
            cStart.DAY_OF_MONTH + " - " + cStart.MONTH + " - " + cStart.YEAR, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (cEnd.after(cStart) || ((cEnd.DAY_OF_MONTH == cStart.DAY_OF_MONTH) && (cEnd.MONTH == cStart.MONTH))) {
        max.set(Calendar.YEAR, cStart.YEAR);
        max.set(Calendar.MONTH, cStart.MONTH);
        max.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cStart.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        max.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7);
        Toast.makeText(this,
                max.DAY_OF_MONTH + " - " + max.MONTH + " - " + max.YEAR,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (cEnd.before(max)) {
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    else{
    return false;}
}
```

But it throws a null exception. im declaring the cStart and cEnd so i have no idea what it is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use math for this?

```
cEnd.getTimeInMillis() - cStart.getTimeInMillis() > (7L * 24L * 60L * 60L * 1000L)
```

Or, thanks to [@Sam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1267661/sam), you can make this simpler using [`DateUtils.WEEK_IN_MILLIS`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#WEEK_IN_MILLIS):

```
cEnd.getTimeInMillis() - cStart.getTimeInMillis() > DateUtils.WEEK_IN_MILLIS
```

**How it works:** `Calendar.getTime().getTime()` will return a `long` of the milliseconds value. Just subtract them (to get the difference), then check if it's greater than `604800000L` (milliseconds in a week, per above formula).

This should provide no `NullPointerException` if run when `cStart` and `cEnd` are non-null.

Comment: Beat me to it, but I'll offer the constant [`DateUtils.WEEK_IN_MILLIS`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#WEEK_IN_MILLIS) rather calculating it out and suggest using `Math.abs()`.

Comment: @Sam Good call, I learned something new today! I'll try to work that into the post.

Comment: this would work even if i'm not setting all the fields other then day month and year?

Comment: @UnbrandedTech Correct. It will assume midnight for both times, and will produce a valid millisecond value.

Comment: @Eric When you call `Calendar#getTime()` you are creating a Date object only to call `getTime()` on that, you could speed things up with `Calendar#getTimeInMillis()`.

Comment: @Sam ... what a day. Thanks again. :P

Answer (score 0):

Eric's answer works and is probably the best solution to your problem.

To fix your own code; however, you have to use `cEnd.get( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH )` instead of `cEnd.DAY_OF_MONTH` and so on for the rest of them.